# Host Second Flutter Project on GitHub Pages

Tags: flutter, github, hosting, github-pages

It sounds like I am experiencing a problem with hosting a new repository on your website hosted on GitHub Pages.

To expand on my issue, I am trying to host a new repository called "graduation_project" at https://mh0386.github.io/graduation_project/, but I am only seeing a blank white background instead of the expected content.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

I checked my GitHub repository settings to make sure they were configured correctly. I navigated to the settings tab of your repository and scrolled down to the "GitHub Pages" section. I make sure that the "Source" option is set to "Deploy from a branch", the "Branch" option is set to "gh-pages", "/root" is selected as a source, and that the "Custom domain" field is empty. The settings look correct.

Comment: When you did `flutter build web` you didn't specify the --base-href. You should have made that `/graduation_project/`      This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="/">